# How to install Horde Webmail on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php

Am using Ubuntu 14.04. Am stuck with the following issue:

My goal is to install and have running **HORDER GROUPWARE 5.2** on my Domain/Hosting:

Download on Github: 
  https:// github .com/horde/horde/releases/tag/groupware-5.2.2

Installation on Github: 
 https://github.com/horde/horde/tree/master/bundles/groupware

Demo: 
 http://demo.horde.org/

> Quick Install
>
> > These are very terse instructions how to install Horde Groupware and
> >     its prerequisites on a LAMP sytem. They are addressed to experienced
> >     administrators who know exactly what they are doing.  For more
> >     detailed instructions, start reading below at Prerequisites_.
>
> 1. Compiling PHP for Apache 2::
>
>    cd php-x.x.x/
>       ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs2 \
>                   --with-gettext --enable-mbstring=all --enable-mbregex \
>                   --with-gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
>                   [--with-mysql|--with-pgsql|--with-oci8]
>                   [--with-tidy]
>                   [--with-ftp]
>       make
>       make install

Can't even start with this method couse there is not such "php-x.x.x" folder on my ubuntu root, and there is not such think on internet called "compiling php for apache2". Any idea?

> 2. Restart Apache.
> 3. Register Horde PEAR channel::
>
>    pear channel-discover pear.horde.org
> 4. Set Horde installation directory::
>
>    pear install horde/horde_role
>       pear run-scripts horde/horde_role
> 5. Install Horde Groupware::
>
>    pear install -a -B horde/groupware
> 6. Run installation script::
>
>    groupware-install
> 7. Test Horde Groupware::
>
>    http:// your-server /horde/test.php

So I try to install it with the other way that is explained on the INSTALLATION guide:

> Prerequisites
>
> The following prerequisites are **REQUIRED** for Horde Groupware to
>   function properly.
>
> 1. A webserver that supports PHP.
>
>    Horde Groupware is primarily developed under the Apache and
>      Lighttpd    webservers, which we recommend.  These servers are
>      available from:
>
>    http:// httpd.apache .org/
>        http:// www.lighttpd .net/

(MY NOTE: i use Apache 2 I have LAMP already installed and functioning well on my OS)
 OK! Done,

> 2. A web server with PATH_INFO support.
>
>    The dynamic interfaces of Horde Groupware requires a web server
>      that    correctly sets the PATH_INFO environment variable for all PHP
>      scripts. Every    modern web server supports this, but you might have
>      to enable this feature    in the web server configuration.  e.g.
>      Apache servers require::
>
>    AcceptPathInfo On
>
>    Lighttpd servers require::
>
>    "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"

Can't continue from this point couse I can't find on internet "How to config the web server apache and change AcceptPathInfo to ON,

> 3. PHP 5.3.0 or above.
>
>    PHP is the interpreted language in which Horde Groupware is
>      written.
>
>    .. Note:: If possible, you should install PHP with your operating
>      system's
>               package manager. Alternatively you build PHP yourself.
>
>    To build PHP from sources, you can obtain it at
>
>    http:// www.php .net/
>
>    Follow the instructions in the PHP package to build PHP for your
>      one of the following    options::
>      system. If    you use Apache, be sure to build PHP as a library with
>
>    --with-apache
>         --with-apxs
>         --with-apxs2
>
> *etc, etc, etc more on the INSTALLATION link.*

Any idea on how to keep installing it? there is no resources on internet (videos, or tutorials) on how to install it in a different way or somethink, only for older versions like HORDE GROUPWARE 1.2 but this is really old software, what am trying to install is the 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horde is not just an application, rather a bundle of various packages, each performing a certain task. Each of these has in turn its own dependencies that must be set up beforehand. Packaging (and maintaining) something like this would be a huge load of work impacting relatively few users; thus manual install is pretty much your only option.

At the Community Wiki you have a [detailed installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Horde4%20Mail%20And%20Groupware%20Server), that may facilitate the task to some extent. But it still requires some commitment.

Comment: Here is what "saved me" I have HORDE operating and running!!
https://bitnami.com/stack/horde/installer